# Import events from a calendarList to primary calendar in gcal API in Javascript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

- I'm using the sample document in the Google Calendar API. I can see all my calendar events but I just can't find a way to merge the data from a calendarList to the current data using Javascript.

Here's what I have:

```
function listUpcomingEvents() {
    gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'primary',
      'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
      'showDeleted': false,
      'singleEvents': true,
      'maxResults': 10,
      'orderBy': 'startTime'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      var events = response.result.items;
      appendPre('');

      if (events.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          var event = events[i];
          var when = event.start.dateTime;

          var calEventTitle = event.summary;
          var eventStatus = event.status;
          if (!when) {
            when = event.start.date;
          }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason why your not doing this is Google Apps Script?

Comment: Not really, this is my first attempt at tinkering with google's API.

Comment: Well this is much more easily done in Google Apps Script.  [CalendarApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app) [SpreadsheetApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app).  You can put all of your code in a .gs file and to begin with you'll will probably find it easier to work from the script editor contained within a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to `merge calendar events` to your **`local variable`** here is an easy example of how to do it.

1. Create calendarEvents array
2. List calendar events by using [calendar.events.list()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) method
3. Add result data to calendarEvents
4. Print your data

```js
// 1
let calendarEvents = []; 

function listEvents(auth){

  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
// 2
  calendar.events.list({

    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: "2020-1-1T22:00:00.000Z",
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime'

  }, (err, res) => {

    if (err) return console.log('Error #1001 - The Calendar API returned an error: ' + err);

// 3
    const events = res.data.items;    
    if (events.length) {
      events.map((event, i) => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        calendarEvents.push(`\n ${start} - ${event.summary}`);
      });
// 4      
    console.log(calendarEvents)

    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    }

  });

}
```

---

If you want to **`update calendar event`** you can make use of [calendar.events.update()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update)

Here is an easy example:

```js
function updateEvent(auth){

  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});

  calendar.events.update({
      "calendarId": "primary",
      "eventId": "___eventId___", // how to get eventId, scroll down
      "resource": {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2020-01-15T05:00:00-05:00"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2020-01-15T06:00:00-05:00"
        },
        "location": "Updated location",
        "summary": "Updated summary",
        "attendees": [
          {
            "email":"updatedEmail@gmail.com"
          }
        ]
      }

  }, (err, res) => {

    if (err) return console.log('Error #1002 - The Calendar API returned an error: ' + err);

  });

}
```

---

### How to get eventId?

Make a use of events.list() method and in response use console.log(res.data.items.events), here is an example:

```js
function listEvents(auth) {

  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
  calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: "2020-1-1T22:00:00.000Z",
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  }, (err, res) => {

    if (err) return console.log('Error #1001 - The Calendar API returned an error: ' + err);

        const events = res.data.items;
        console.log(events);

  });

}
```

and this is the output, I have only 1 event,

so the `id` is `12sv34jssjjov56jq7c8vlbjkd`

```
[
  {
    kind: 'calendar#event',
    etag: '"3157989414186000"',
    id: '12sv34jssjjov56jq7c8vlbjkd',
    status: 'confirmed',
    htmlLink: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=blablabla',
    created: '2020-01-14T09:23:46.000Z',
    updated: '2020-01-14T09:38:27.093Z',
    summary: 'Updated summary',
    location: 'Updated location',
    creator: { email: 'myEmail@gmail.com', self: true },
    organizer: { email: 'myEmail@gmail.com', self: true },
    start: { dateTime: '2020-01-15T05:00:00-05:00' },
    end: { dateTime: '2020-01-15T06:00:00-05:00' },
    iCalUID: 'myEmail@gmail.com',
    sequence: 1,
    attendees: [ [Object] ],
    hangoutLink: 'https://meet.google.com/123-4567-890',
    conferenceData: {
      entryPoints: [Array],
      conferenceSolution: [Object],
      conferenceId: '123-4567-890',
      signature: '32ipslWNrbuVDju4rHvyOpVzH/gj'
    },
    reminders: { useDefault: true }
  }
]
```

I hope these examples make things clearer.
If something goes wrong, you can always test your request directly in a browser by using Try This Api which is located in a right side of [Google Calendar API Reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference) page

[image]

## References:

- [Google Calendar API Reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference)
- [calendar.events.list()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)
- [calendar.events.update()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update)